# Connect to Neo4j through C#

Tags: neo4j, database-connection, neo4jclient

I have developed a web application using Asp.net, where I am using Neo4j client to connect to my Neo4j database.

```
static GraphClient client = new GraphClient(new Uri(url), username, password);
client.Connect();
```

However this requires me to open the Neo4J desktop app and run the database before I can run my web app.
I wonder if it is possible to run the webapp without opening the Neo4J instance physically. i.e., The webapp should communicate with Neo4J in the background like we normally do with SQL databases.

Answer (score 1):

The neo4j Desktop is only really for use during development.

To have a neo4j server that runs all the time, you should download an appropriate non-Desktop release [from this page](https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/#releases), and install it on a machine or environment that is always available. [Chapter 2 of the Operations Manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.3/installation/) has installation instructions.